# Translated strings not showing up when i switch languages in Django site

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have a reasonably simple Django (1.1) site where i need some basic interface and other texts to be translated between two languages. I've created the po files using `manage.py makemessages`, translated them (using poedit), and compiled the mo files using `manage.py compilemessages` as outlined in the [i18n docs for Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/).

But the problem is; most strings still show up in the original language...

- i checked that the po files actually contain all strings
- i checked that the mo files were freshly generated after the last translation effort
- the language does actually change when i switch using the `getlang()` method
- a few strings -do- end up being translated when i switch
- but most don't...

Not really sure where else to look... Is there any app that i can use to check whether the compiled mo files are valid & complete for instance? Could these strings be cached? (i'm not using any caching middleware)

Comment: Did you create the files for seperate apps or the whole project?

Comment: I created & translated them for the whole project, i.e. i ran above command from the project root not for each app individually

Comment: Further to lazer's comment, you have marked up the strings you want to translate in your own models/templates, yep?

Comment: Yes i'm using `{% trans "some string" %}` throughout my templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!! While pulling out hair trying to figure out what was causing my woes i commented out `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` from my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and refreshed the page in an attempt to try everything. Obviously that just turned off translation all together but when i turned it back on again, all my fine translated strings were showing up as they should have been all along.

So i'm guessing something, somewhere get's compiled/cached when you turn on the locale middleware and the only way to refresh it is to turn it off and on. Restarting the server didn't help so this a bit counter intuitive, but who cares it works! :)